# JS: имя свойства объекта из переменной

Tags: javascript, объекты

Необходимо обратиться к вложенному свойству объекта js, имя которого задано переменной. Общая картина такова:

1. Есть объект, имеющий 3 свойства. При этом третье свойство может иметь неограниченное количество вложенных свойств.
2. Нужно добавить к этому третьему свойству объекта новое вложенное свойство.

Насколько я поняла, мне необходимо сначала посчитать количество вложенных свойств объекта. Что-то вроде этого:

```
var x = Object.keys(имя_объекта).lenth;
```

только для вложенных свойств.

**Вопрос 1:** Можно ли написать так?

```
var x = Object.keys(имя_объекта)[2].lenth;
var x++;
```

**Вопрос 2:** Как мне теперь добавить новое вложенное свойство (имя/номер которого задано в переменной x) и записать в него значение?

Надеюсь, мой вопрос можно понять. 
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Пример объекта, в который нужно добавить новое свойство (например, 4):

```
var order = {
    name: "Петя",
    phone: "+79211234567",
    1:{'<tr><td>Однокомнатная квартира</td><td>метро Пионерская</td><td>пр.Королёва, 35</td>С мебелью<td>Все есть, пешком от метро, залог</td></tr>'},

    2:{'<tr><td>Однокомнатная квартира</td><td>метро пр.Большевиков</td><td>ул.Ворошилова, 12</td>С мебелью<td>Стеклопакеты, паркет, посудомоечная машина</td></tr>'},

    3:{'<tr><td>Студия</td><td>метро Московская</td><td>ул.Типанова, 4</td>Пустая<td>Для семейной пары</td></tr>'}
};
```

Как вариант, можно свойства объекта назвать flat1, flat2, .... flat4

Comment: покажите пример объекта

Comment: `x++;` вот это только с числами сработает ( значит у вас скорее всего массив )

Comment: Пример приложила. Может, ерунду написала? Я учусь только :(

Comment: что-то  странный у вас несколько пример. не соответствует что выше написано, где вложенное-то?

Comment: а нумерация всегда с 1 начинается? Скажите, а вы можете поменять формат объекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашего конкретного случая, это делается так

```js
var order = {
    name: "Петя",
    phone: "+79211234567",
    1: 'some data',
    2: 'some data',
    3: 'some data',
};

function addNumKey(obj, val) {
  const numKeys = Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => !isNaN(key)) // нужны только числовые ключи
    .map(Number) // делаем их настоящими числами
    // сортируем на всякий случай
    // ( в обратном порядке, что бы легче получить максимальный элемент, он будет первым
    .sort((a, b) => b - a);
  
  const nextKeyIndex = numKeys[0] + 1;
  obj[nextKeyIndex] = val;
}

addNumKey(order, 'new value');
console.log(order);
```

*Но, как написали в другом ответе, лучше для этого использовать массив, так как операция упрощается в разы.*

Comment: если предполагать, что ключи расположены в возрастающем порядке.

Comment: @teran добавил сортировку)

Comment: можно еще через `Math.max` сделать

Comment: да уж куда лучше, чем сортировать :)

Answer (score 1):

Для такой задачи используют обычный массив, так:

```js
let order = {
  name: "Петя",
  phone: "+79211234567",
  trs: [
    '<tr><td>Однокомнатная квартира</td><td>метро Пионерская</td><td>пр.Королёва, 35</td>С мебелью<td>Все есть, пешком от метро, залог</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Однокомнатная квартира</td><td>метро пр.Большевиков</td><td>ул.Ворошилова, 12</td> мебелью<td>Стеклопакеты, паркет, посудомоечная машина</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Студия</td><td>метро Московская</td><td>ул.Типанова, 4</td>Пустая<td>Для семейной пары</td></tr>',
  ],
};

let newRow = '<tr><td colspan="5">Четвертая строка!</td></tr>';
order.trs.push( newRow );

console.log( order.trs[0] );
console.log( order.trs[1] );
console.log( order.trs[2] );
console.log( order.trs[3] );

let bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');

bubu.innerHTML = order.trs.join("");
```

```css
td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #b89868;
}
```

```html
<table id="bubu"></table>
```

Comment: Мне эти данные в дальнейшем нужно сохранять в localStorage, а lS работает только с объектами. Поэтому и добавлять придется свойство объекта. Насколько я могу понять, мне придется эти свойства считать и добавлять следующее с ключом, увеличенным на 1. А в значение уже записывать код строки <tr>...</tr>

Comment: @Наталья Со строками) Сохранение: `localStroage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(order) );` и получение: `let obj = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('test') ); console.log(obj);` а массивы - точно такие же объекты, только с нумерованными ключами и расширенными возможностями)

Comment: Ну, да . Я сериализую свои объекты :) Мозг сломан уже, вах-вах!